Install `venv` without sudo access
I am in a Ubuntu 22.04 cluster with Python==3.11 and pip==24.2 and no sudo access. When I try to create a virtual environment python3 -m venv .env I get:
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

any idea how to do it? I only need 'venv', for 'virtualenv' or 'pyenv' I have found how to do it.

I recommend you talk to the maintainers of the cluster to fix the Python installation. A Python installation without its complete standard library (which includes venv and ensurepip) is considered broken. -- Is there a  specific reason you want to use venv in particular and are not satisfied with virtualenv?

@sinoroc: unfortunately, many Linux distribs only install a reduced Python environment by default. In fact only what is required by the other packages. IMHO the correct way is to contact the sysadmin and ask them for the python3-venv package.

Don't edit your post to include the solution. Either write an answer, or delete your post if you think no one else will benefit from an answer.

Sorry, I had run it with -m, just forgot to mention it here. I found the workaround with 'python3 -m venv --without-pip .env'! it works

And you found that... where? Because if you found that in another SO post, your question is simply a duplicate.

@sinoroc "A Python installation without its complete standard library is considered broken." - Not on Debian

Edited with source

It is actually same to that topic in the link. Should I delete the post, what do you suggest

@Mike I am well aware. But Debian does not get to decide what Python is or is not. If the full standard library is not installed then Python is broken, period. Sure, for some of its own system packages Debian can get away with skipping some parts of Python, it's their business, but from the user's point of view it is a broken Python.

Problem fixed as suggested in Ensurepip module not existing, how to install manually? :
python3 -m venv --without-pip .env
source .env/bin/activate

And things work now as should :)

No reason to post an answer if your question is a duplicate: that post already has the answer.
